# arrayContains in subCollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Cant seem to understand if arrayContains works on subCollections in Firestore.

This code does not return any data

```
Firestore.firestore()
  .collection("all_chatrooms")
  .whereField("postmoderators", arrayContains: userId)
```

However specifying the targeted collection path does...

```
Firestore.firestore()
  .collection("all_chatrooms")
  .document("randomId")
  .collection("chatroom")
  .whereField("postmoderators", arrayContains: userId)
```

is there a way to search for an array within subCollections without specifying a documentId?

Do you maybe have to store userIds within a map to be able to search within subColletions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do the documents in your `all_chatrooms` collection have a `postmoderators` field?

Comment: Only the subCollection ("chatroom") contains the array "postmoderators". I am trying to make a query to reach the subCollection without having to specify any documentId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore queries are shallow, meaning that when you query a specific collection "C1", only the documents from this collection are returned, and not the documents in the subcollections of the documents in "C1".

However, in your case, [Collection Group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) may "come to the rescue". As indicated in the doc:

> A collection group consists of all collections with the same ID. For
> example, if each document in your cities collection has a
> subcollection called landmarks, all of the landmarks subcollections
> belong to the same collection group.

So if all the docs in the `all_chatrooms` collection have a subcollection named `chatroom` you can use a Collection Group query as follows:

```
Firestore.firestore().collectionGroup("chatroom").whereField("postmoderators", arrayContains: userId)
```

Of course, by doing so you will get ALL the docs (with `userId` in `postmoderators`) in ALL the `chatroom` subcollections of ALL the docs in the `all_chatrooms` collection.